# Excel VBA to get average

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the average of an unknown number of cells using VBA behind a sheet(using command button). I have a for loop that looks for rows where the values are equal. while they are equal, I find the first cell and the last cell so I can get an average. I am getting an error when using the Average function. I think because I have concatenated the range into a variable. In the end my statement with the Average function looks like this.

```
sheets("LibraryRes").Range(pCol & pRow).value = sheets("LibraryRes").Average(Range(iRange).value)
```

```
pCol = i
pRow = 3
iRange is concatenated from firstRow (i4) and lastRow(i6) so iRange looks like "i4:i6" in debug
```

all of these variables are STRING

I get runtime error 438 saying the object doesn't support this property or method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average`. Edit: also change `.Range(pCol & pRow)` to `cells(pcol, prow)`.

Comment: `iRange = Range("I" & fRow & ":I" & lRow)`/
`ActiveSheet.Cells(pCol, pRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(iRange)` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I still get a mismatch error on iRange = Range("I" & fRow & ":I" & lRow). It might be my dim data types? I initially had fRow and lRow set to integer and iRange as string. I also tried iRange as Range.

Comment: What does `debug.print` say? Please post all the code.

Comment: I was about to get it to work with your solution. My syntax was off. Thanks!